# What does "trading with the street" mean?

Tags: trading

When someone is talking about their job duties in various positions, and then says that, as a trader, they were "trading with the street," what does that mean? And opposed to what? Is it that they were working with institutions and not retail?

Comment: My first thought was trading directly with wall street firms (e.g. CDSs, bond, or other non-exchange instruments). IOW, wall street firms were the _counterparty_ in their deals, whether they were working for an institution or not.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding that would most likely mean trading alongside consensus analyst estimates, and published analyst sentiment.

(They could also be using jargon that nobody knows and they could also have no idea what they are talking about.)